# Ubuntu & Windows

Tags: dual-boot

As I said in another post, I'm a new Ubuntu user.
I've installed Ubuntu and I did not delete  windows 7 , but after installing Ubuntu, windows was in boot menu but when I clicked on windows to load,I see this error:

A disk read error occured
press ctrl+Alt+ Del to restart

I'm using Ubuntu  right now, but I can't switch to windows ..

I don't know what to do in order to have Ubuntu and windows simultaneously ..

Comment: elaborate the question by adding drive and installation information

Answer (score 0):

Insert Windows 7 CD -> Restart -> BIOS -> BOOT PRIORITY -> Make CD/DVD boot first then Windows 7 CD loads select `Repair` . This will repair your Boot Loader of Windows 7. This will start your Windows 7.

Windows 7 boot loader cannot recognise GRUB (linux) boot loader but GRUB can, So now configure grub boot loader(linux boot loader) by following this post.

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd#.UxcE73gyoW0

In this article Live CD means bootable pendrive or CD which you used for Installing Ubuntu.

Comment if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering ..
I did not understand if I should do these instructions in windows or in Ubuntu Live ..

Comment: Do u still have usb from which you installed ubuntu? if yes thn do it again n select "Try Ubuntu" thn open "Terminal" n execute those commands!